# How do I change styles to an already created list control?

Tags: c++, mfc, clistctrl

I have created

```
 pMyListControl = new CListCtrl; 
    pMyListControl->Create(WS_CHILD| WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL | LBS_NOTIFY | LVS_REPORT | LVS_SINGLESEL, rect, pTabControl, LIST_ID);
```

On some tabs the list will only allow single select like the above code, but on some tabs it will not have LVS_SINGLESEL to allow for multiple item selections.
The list is created with a default tab that doesn't allow for multiple selection.

Can I change the style, without having to create a new listcntrl depending on my tab selection? Is there a method for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`CWnd::ModifyStyle()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class?view=msvc-160#modifystyle) method, eg:

```cpp
// turn on single selection
pMyListControl->ModifyStyle(0, LVS_SINGLESEL);

// turn off single selection
pMyListControl->ModifyStyle(LVS_SINGLESEL, 0);
```